# Why many website do not allow to access the "last-modified" header?

Tags: python, webserver, http, website, headers

I was developing a python program to scrape data from web, while requesting page from the website I checked the header field, It contained all other field such as server, via, date etc but most of the website responses did not contain "Last-Modified" field in it ? What is the reason behind it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably for [this reason](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/apache-speed-last-modified/):

> If you remove the Last-Modified and ETag header, you will totally eliminate If-Modified-Since and If-None-Match requests and their 304 Not Modified Responses, so a file will stay cached without checking for updates until the Expires header indicates new content is available!
>
> By removing both the ETag header and the Last-Modified headers from your static files (images, javascript, css) browsers and caches will not be able to validate the cached version of the file vs. the real version. By also including a Cache-Control header and Expires header, you can specify that certain files be cached for a certain period of time, and you magically (this is a really unique trick I promise) eliminate any validation requests!

The `ETag` header is just a unique code (typically a hash) that a browser can check to see if a resource has changed.

So, by not including this header or  `ETag`, but including an `Expires` and `Cache-Control` header:

- the browser will use its cached copy until the duration in the `Expires` header is past
- and also will not send validation requests (I think these would be `HEAD` requests to get headers to check for an updated `Last-Modified` date)  to check the modification state.

Making browsers not send validation requests, but simply invalidate cached copies at a future date, cuts down on HTTP requests and increases webserver performance, which is important for servers facing the Internet at large where they get hit with bots and scrapers and such.

Comment: Then does this also mean that web caching or proxy server will not work as it iwon't be able to access last modified since?

Comment: It means instead of reading the "Last-Modified" header each time to check if it's different, it will simply wait until after the "Expires:" date to age out cache items.  So it'll work, just a different and more efficient way.